# Maven Archetype:create java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Tags: maven

Quiero crear un arquetipo a partir de un proyecto existente, para lo cual me sitúo en el directorio dónde esta el `POM.XML` de este proyecto y ejecuto la instrucción

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

obteniendo como resultado

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

Tengo instalada la versión 3.3.9 de Maven, y utilizo JDK 1.8.
Además, como podéis ver en la traza, la librería common-lang existe en mi repositorio de librerías ( aunque parece estar usando la 2.4 cuando he comprobado que tengo descargada también la 2.6 ).

He probado también con otras instrucciones maven como "generate" y siempre dá el mismo error.

Por otro lado, el proyecto compila sin problemas.

**Esta es la traza del error**

```
> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]                                
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building EncodeDetectorLibrary 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:create-from-project
> (default-cli) > generate-sources @ EncodeDetectorLibrary >>> [INFO] 
> [INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:create-from-project
> (default-cli) < generate-sources @ EncodeDetectorLibrary <<< [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:create-from-project
> (default-cli) @ EncodeDetectorLibrary --- [WARNING] Error
> initializing:
> org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.DefaultVelocityComponent@5a12c728
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.initialize(ResourceManagerImpl.java:161)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeResourceManager(RuntimeInstance.java:730)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:263)
>       at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:93)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.DefaultVelocityComponent.initialize(DefaultVelocityComponent.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Pending.activate(BeanScheduler.java:156)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:185)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
>       ... 44 more
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] Total time: 1.219 s
>     [INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-23T17:56:33+01:00
>     [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/155M
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:create-from-project
> (default-cli) on project EncodeDetectorLibrary: Execution default-cli
> of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:create-from-project
> failed: A required class was missing while executing
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:create-from-project:
> org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
>     [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
>     [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0
>     [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
>     [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/3.0.0/maven-archetype-plugin-3.0.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/3.0.0/archetype-catalog-3.0.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/3.0.0/archetype-descriptor-3.0.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/3.0.0/archetype-common-3.0.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.21/plexus-utils-3.0.21.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.2/maven-invoker-2.2.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.9.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.9.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.0.0/maven-shared-utils-3.0.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-script-interpreter/1.0/maven-script-interpreter-1.0.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar
>     [ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/Nylon/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar
>     [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
>     [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
>     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>     [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Según terminaba de publicar la pregunta, me dí cuenta que al final de la traza aparece una url de consulta en caso de error:

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

No descubren nada nuevo, pero al final, aplicando la idea de que la solución más sencilla es la más probable, corregí el error.

Simplemente me fuí a **.m2/repository y quité todas las versiones anteriores a la 2.6 de common-lang.**

volví a lanzar el comando mvn archetype:create-from-project y ahora sí funcionó correctamente.

Es una solución en falso, por que no sé cual fué realmente la causa, pero puedo seguir trabajando.

Aquí lo dejo para futuros lectores.

Un saludo.

Comment: Enhorabuena por seguir perseverando y encontrarlo; puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta (el "tick" verde debajo del número de puntos) para ayudar a otros usuarios a encontrarla.